# ¿Cómo se hace para que una clase herede las variables y métodos de otra clase en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, clase, herencia

Me gustaría saber cúal es la forma correcta de declarar una clase para que herede las variables y metodos de otra clase en JavaScript.

Si declaro esta clase:

```
class Identidad
{
    constructor (nombre, apellido1, apellido2) 
    {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido1 = apellido1;
        this.apellido2 = apellido2;
    }
    metodo()
   {
   }
};
```

¿Cómo hago para que esta otra herede las variables y metodos de la primera?

```
class DatosPersonales: public Identidad
{
    constructor (nombre, apellido1, apellido2, edad, telefono, direccion):Identidad(nombre, apellido1, apellido2) 
    {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido1 = apellido1;
        this.apellido2 = apellido2;
        this.telefono  = telefono;
        this.direccion = direccion;
        this.edad = edad;
    }   
};
```

NOTA: La forma en la que está puesta es como se haría en C++, evidentemente asi no funciona. De hecho me da este error al ponerlo así.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Comment: de donde sacaste esta sintaxis? `: public Identidad`

Comment: Es la que se usa en C++....  es solo un ejemplo... me gustaría saber como se hace lo mismo en JavaScript

Comment: eso no quiere decir que se usa en JS desde ahi esta mal el ejercicio

Comment: Lo sé, por eso pregunto cual es la forma correcta de hacerlo

Comment: A. Cedano!! Perfecto!! Ahi está la solución... hay que usar (extends) ¿Cómo lo encontraste tan rápido? Yo llevo una hora buscando... ¿Que hago con mi post?¿Lo borro?

Comment: Iván lo encontré tan rápido porque escribí la respuesta a esa pregunta hace ya un tiempo y cuando te leí sabía que en el sitio ya existía algo explicando detalladamente el tema. Incluso, hay [más preguntas / respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=herencia+javascript) sobre el tema.

Comment: Si, tienes razón!! Y además creo que lo he usado alguna vez en PHP...  es lo que pasa cuando se es un novato y empiezas con un leguaje nuevo... todo lo asocias al lenguaje que mejor dominas... Muchas gracias @element

Comment: @ A. Cedano. Con razón!! ¿Entonces que hago con este post ¿lo borro o lo dejo así?

Comment: Si, estuve leyendo cientos de post  antes de preguntar. Pero ninguno de los que vi tenia la respuesta exacta a mi pregunta. Excepto el tuyo!! . @ A. Cedano  Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!!